# Given that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges ($a_n >0$), then does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^{3} \sin(n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges ($a_n >0$), then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^{3} \sin(n)$:

a) converges

b) diverges

c) does not exist

d) None of the above

My attempt: If we were given that $(a_n)$ is monotonically decreasing, then using the Abel-Olivier-Pringsheim criterion (Theorem 2.16 in [these](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/3100supp.pdf) notes) we could conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} na_n=0$ from which we obtain $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq k,$ we have $na_n<1$ which implies $|a_n^{3}\sin(n)|<\dfrac{1}{n^3}$ which by the comparison test means that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^{3} \sin(n)$ converges absolutely.

But we are not given that $(a_n)$ is monotonically decreasing. At best, we have a monotonically decreasing subsequence tending to $0.$ Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: $a_n\to0$, hence there exists $k$ with $|a_n|\le k$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\sum_n a_n$ converges, $a_n\to 0$. There is some $N$ such that $n\geq N\implies 0<a_n\leq 1$.

For $n\geq N$, $|a_n^{3} \sin(n)|\leq a_n^3\leq a_n$.

Therefore, $\sum_n a_n^{3} \sin(n)$ converges absolutely, hence converges.

Comment: Thanks, was definitely overthinking it.

Answer (score 4):

Eventually, the $a_n$s are small. Then
$$
|a_n^3 \sin n| \leq |a_n|^3 \leq |a_n| = a_n.
$$
Now compare and use absolute convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$ and thus you can find $N$ sufficiently large enough so that $a_n <1$ for $n > N$.  After this $a_n^3 < a_n$ for all $n > N$.  This tell us that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^3 = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n^3 + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_n^3 < \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n^3 + \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_n <\infty $$

And finally we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^3 \sin(n) < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^3 $$

since $\sin(n) < 1$.